# Call function ON a string (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function

How can I call a function directly on a string?

```
var test = function(x){
  console.log(x);
};

test();
```

**
The above logs 'undefined' as it should.

If I try:

```
"test".test();
```

I get:

```
"error"
"TypeError: \"test\".test is not a function.
```

But test is a function. So even if I try:

```
var example = "test";

example.test();
```

I get:

```
"error"
"TypeError: example.test is not a function
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's a function, but what is its connection with an arbitrary string? How JS would know that a string does have a function with that name?

Comment: To be clear: If you are trying to pass an argument to a user defined function, see Thilo's answer. If you are looking to add a method to the `String` object and then call that method on a `String` type value, see Luke's answer.

Comment: Yes, `test` (the global variable) is a function, but `example.test` or `"test".test` (the string properties) are not, as your error messages state.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on the other answers a bit, you've created a function called `test()` but that function doesn't belong to any objects, and it doesn't belong to any Strings. You haven't defined a function called `test()` for Strings, hence the error.

To do that, you can try the following:

```
String.prototype.test = function() {
    console.log(this);
};
"hello".test();
```

Read up [here](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) on prototypes. Essentially, objects in javascript have properties and methods, and they also have the properties and methods of their prototypes.

Comment: `.test()` is a [method of `RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: True, although it's my understanding that the OP is just messing around with functions. I may be incorrect?

Comment: I don't think you're incorrect in your assessment of OP, but I was just pointing that out because you said "..doesn't belong to any objects"

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly what I'm looking for. I tried searching for this answer but without knowing about prototypes it was hard to find what I was looking for. I appreciate the help.

Comment: Ah. I merely meant that the function that was defined right there is kinda floating, not that there was no function named test in existence :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `test` is a function but `String.prototype.test` is not a function. The value is `undefined` and invoking an `undefined` value using invocation operator throws a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 1):

The question is a bit unclear, but if you are trying to pass a String as your argument to the function, that would be

```
 test("hello");

 var example = "hello";
 test(example);
```

Comment: It’s perfectly clear to me: he asks how to call a prototype function, or method.

Comment: Not so sure about that. Could be just basic question about how to call a function with parameters. It looks like that `x` parameter should be set to the String in question. In languages with unified call syntax, `a.test()` is the same as `test(a)` or `test a`.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define function `test()` on the string first using [Prototypes](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp)

For example:

```
String.prototype.cleanSpaces = function() {
     return this.replace(" ", '');
};
```

now you can call `"test ".cleanSpaces()`

Answer (score 0):

use `prototype`

```
 String.prototype.test = function () {
    console.log(this.toString());
}

'test'.test();
```

it would ouput `test` in console